# How can I stop ZooKeeper on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, zookeeper

I have installed zookeeperd on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016986/best-way-to-start-zookeeper-automatically-on-ubuntu-server-14-04):

Unfortunately this process is somehow not stoppable. I tried even kill -9

```
user@node1:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6$ ps -ef | grep zookeeper
zookeep+  4008     1  8 01:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/java -cp /etc/zookeeper/conf:/usr/share/java/jline.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share/java/netty.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-api.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper.jar -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/var/log/zookeeper -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,ROLLINGFILE org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
```

show process

```
user      4055  2823  0 01:07 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto zookeeper
```

kill it

```
user@node1:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6$ sudo kill -9 4008
```

Check:

```
user@node1:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6$ ps -ef | grep zookeeper
zookeep+  4075     1 24 01:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/java -cp /etc/zookeeper/conf:/usr/share/java/jline.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share/java/netty.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-api.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper.jar -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/var/log/zookeeper -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,ROLLINGFILE org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
```

Try script

```
user@node1:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6$ sudo /etc/init.d/zookeeper stop
user@node1:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6$ ps -ef | grep zookeeper
zookeep+  4075     1 29 01:07 ?        00:00:04 /usr/bin/java -cp /etc/zookeeper/conf:/usr/share/java/jline.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share/java/netty.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-api.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper.jar -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/var/log/zookeeper -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,ROLLINGFILE org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
```

Nothing helps.

How could I stop ZooKeeper?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try:

`sudo service zookeeper stop`

to stop the process. If it does not work you could check [this link](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.3/bk_reference/content/reference_chap3_2.html):

```
Stop ZooKeeper. On the ZooKeeper host machine, execute the following command:

su - zookeeper -c "export ZOOCFGDIR=/etc/zookeeper/conf ; export ZOOCFG=zoo.cfg ;source /etc/zookeeper/conf/zookeeper-env.sh ; /usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh stop"
```

If above commands do not stop the Zookeeper and the kill -9 is also not able to stop then there is perhaps a zombie process. You could check [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work) how to stop such processes if that is the case.

Comment: "sudo service zookeeper stop" worked perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From the zookeper root directory (`cd ~/zookeeper-3.4.6`) run the following command

```
sudo bin/zkServer.sh stop
```

Answer (score 0):

`bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh` did not work on Mac. And a new process was getting spawned when trying to kill the process, even with `SIGTERM`.

Instead, [stop ZooKeeper with Homebrew](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew):

`$ brew services stop zookeeper`

Comment: The question was: '... on Ubuntu'. So anything using `brew` will certainly not apply.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I set an environment variable of $KAFKA_HOME - makes my life easier. If you do, you can create an alias for these sorts of things in the following manner:

```
alias zstop='sudo $KAFKA_HOME/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh'
```

And then you can just type

```
zstop
```

Or, if you installed into `/opt/kafka` for example, you could just type:

```
sudo /opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
```

I also like to create an alias to start zookeeper, here are two lines I added to the bottom of my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias zstart='$KAFKA_HOME/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/zookeeper.properties'
alias zstop=''$KAFKA_HOME/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh'
```